# c++ system call security issue

Tags: c++, cgi, rights

I develop a c++ CGI app that is used under Windows and Linux.
It has to start another app. Currently I am using a system call:

```
system("anotherApp.exe -arguments");
```

For that call I need execute rights for cmd.exe on windows cause the system call starts a shell. This is a security concern since my app is a CGI app and used on a webserver.

Is there another possibiliy to call an app without starting a new shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System() launches a Console Window and runs the program in that console window.

popen() runs the program without a console Window, and redirects console output to a pipe.

CreateProcess() just launches the program.  You pass a flags argument telling it what to do with consoles.  It also allows the program to run with different permissions to the parent program.

If you have no rights for cmd.exe, then system() is off the menu.

popen() may work, as long as the program doesn't need to write to stdout or stderr as that will be lost.

You might be best to write simething like this:

```
bool RunProgram(const std::string &sProgram, bool bWaitForFinish)
{
#if defined(Win32)
    // Launch with CreateProcess()
    // wait if required
#else
    // launch with fork()/exec() or even system()
    // wait if required
#endif
    return error_status;
}
```

Comment: you are right. popen() doesn't work either because i have to write to stdout. but CreateProcess() works fine. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and setup security permissions using that command. Also you can impersonate a restricted user to be sure that the process you are invoking only has the rights you give to it.

Comment: thanks. I will try that. but since I am using windows and linux i would prefer a OS independent solution. I found the function popen(). i will try if it starts a shell too like system().

Comment: @juergen You are right for some reason I thought you said you were only on a Windows machine. That is my fault.

Comment: `popen` and `system` both spawn a shell (on linux and on windows) (and it's called `_popen` in win32). I don't think you'll find a portable way of doing what you're after.

Comment: ok, i can live with that. I guess i will use CreateProcess then.